# How do I generate a Wordcloud with python with an exact list of words including repetitions?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I have a list of words of which I would like to generate a wordcloud in python. Every word should appear exactly once and duplicates should not be taken together. Therefore, I would like to disable the frequency sum-up. Repeat doesn’t work as I do not want random repetition but one that I have predetermined.

In R it worked like a charm, as the tokenization and frequency calculation is separate from the cloud generation:

```
x <- LETTERS
randLet = sample(x,70, replace= TRUE)
wordcloud(randLet, freq = rep(1,70), scale = c(3,.4), max.words = 100, random.order=TRUE,
          random.color=TRUE,
          colors = c("grey50", "blue", "red"))
```

(Here just with letters instead of words.)
[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeHlh.png)

Now I’m getting a headache trying to translate it to python.

So far, I've tried repeat=True but that only randomly repeats letters and does not stick with the frequency in the original data. I also looked into generate_from_frequencies() but from what I've understood you need to insert a dictionary which on its part does not allow for duplicates.

Comment: Could you provide an example input and desired output? It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve for people that don't know R. Anyway, maybe a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is what you need.

Comment: Hi edd313,
thanks for your comment. I've added some R example output. The input was a random list of letters containing the letters displayed in the output. E.g. randLet = ["W", "R", ...,"X"]
I'm not sure that a Counter helps me, as it basically summarizes the input and that is exactly what I'm trying to disable.